# Show Unity Ads Every 5 times scene is loaded. (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, ads

I want to show ads in my 2D game every 5 times the scene is loaded. I tried this:

```
void Update ()
{
    if(GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").transform.position.x == -23) {
        showNumber += 1;
        if(showNumber == 5) {
            if(Advertisement.isReady()){
                Advertisement.Show();
            }
        }
        if(showNumber > 5) {
            showNumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the number only change only once so it would only change once when the main camera's position is -23. Right not it changes every frame.

Edit

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    if(other.name == "Main Camera") {
        showNumber +=1;
        if(showNumber == 5) {
            if(Advertisement.isReady()){
                Advertisement.Show();
            }
        }
        if(showNumber > 5) {
            showNumber = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Put the `showNumber +=1`  oder `showNumber++` into

```
    void Start()
    {
        showNumber +=1;
    }
```

I think it would be easier if you write this value to a textfile and then read it from this textfile, all in the start event and not the update.

Start is called once and the update is called every frame.

Quick and dirty Edit: Place a trigger zone on your desired postion.
Then call an OnTriggerEnter method.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    showNumber +=1;
    if(showNumber == 5) {
        if(Advertisement.isReady()){
            Advertisement.Show();
        }

}
```

Edit: Your problem is that `showNumber +=1;` is called like 30-60 times, depending on your computer.
You could add a bool variable to check if it's a new entry on that point.

```
bool alreadyEntered = false;
void Update ()
{
    if(GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").transform.position.x == -23 && alreadyEntered == false) {
        showNumber += 1;
        alreadyEntered = true;
        if(showNumber == 5) {
            if(Advertisement.isReady()){
                Advertisement.Show();
            }
        }
        if(showNumber > 5) {
            showNumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be called from the start of the scene I want it to be called once when the camera is at that position every 5 times.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I misunterstood your first sentence, I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I attached a script to a gameobject in the desired area(see edit above) but is not working.

Comment: If you didn't close the game you could use the DontDestroyOnLoad Method. [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). But if you want to save the value through a restart you should save the value  (maybe encrypted) in a file on the system.

Comment: You need to add a GameObject with a collider, place it in the desired area. Activate the trigger function on that GameObject.  Maybe you want to watch this tutorial [link](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/colliders-as-triggers)

Answer (score 0):

Save the Show Number in player prefs.

```
private int showNumber{
        get{

            return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("showNumber");
        }
        set{
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("showNumber",value);

        }
    }
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    showNumber +=1;
    if(showNumber == 5) {
        if(Advertisement.isReady()){
            Advertisement.Show();
            showNumber = 0;
        }

}
```